# Reference request: Nonlinear dynamics graduate reference

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

There are already a number of requests for textbooks detailing nonlinear stability theory, chaos theory etc. but many of them are more introductory (e.g. *Strogatz - Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos*)

I've covered all this material before but I'm prone to forgetting the details. I hoped somebody might be able to point me in the direction of a more formal reference text on this subject. Perhaps a graduate level text, that covers major undergraduate material in a fairly mathematically rigorous way, as well as a little extra?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two suggestions of the textbooks:

- [Introduction to Applied Nonlinear Dynamical Systems and Chaos](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387001778) by Wiggins
- [Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387951164) by Perko

The second one is more or less self-contained, whereas the first one assumes good first ODE course (but reviews the necessary material). These are *textbooks* and not research monographs, which is more applicable to the texts in the other answer.

Comment: Another vote for Wiggins book. Hard to beat in terms of pedagogical value. Holmes/Guckenheimer is more of a reference text comparatively speaking, and less comprehensive.

Comment: Wiggins book does look particularly good, difficult to shell out for when a quick Google returns a full PDF as the second result! But nothing beats the feel of a decent desk reference.

Answer (score 3):

"Nonlinear Oscillations, Dynamical Systems ,and Bifurcation of Vector Fields" by John Guckenheimer and Philip Holmes comes to mind. I took a class on Dynamical Systems with the first author many years ago and this was the text. I see people using the book by Strogatz and always feel that it is just not at the same level.

Comment: I would add the book Geometric theory of dynamical systems by Palis and de Melo, and maybe Dynamical Systems and chaos by Broer and Takens. There are plenty of references of a graduate level, but dynamical systems (in particular nonlinear dynamics) is a very broad topic. There is the encyclopaedia of dynamical systems as well (by V.I. Arnold), which treats many nonlinear phenomena in a rigorous way. Another applied mathematics book would be Nonlinear Differential Equations by Jordan and Smith.

Comment: Agree V.I. Arnold should not be missed , too many to list. Perhaps Hirsch & Smale should be mentioned; An older classic is "Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, And Linear Algebra", also more recently "Differential Equations , Dynamical Systems, And An Introduction To Chaos".

Comment: The Wiggins book has basically replaced Guckenheimer and Holmes. Wiggins is now THE graduate textbook for ODEs and Dynamical systems, and way more comprehensive.