# Textbook recommendation for differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm in need of a textbook/workbook that covers differential equations with plenty of practice questions and exercises.
A textbook with a particular focus on Nonlinear Ordinary Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1244323/recommended-second-textbook-for-dynamical-systems?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709463/reference-request-nonlinear-dynamics-graduate-reference/709526#709526

Comment: I recommend: 1) Boyce and DiPrima, 2) Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos by Strogatz, 3) Hirsch and Smale.